# Javascript partial application

Tags: javascript, prototype

im trying to augument the Function prototype with currying but im getting unexpected results. It works fine in some cases but not all.

Here is the code that im using the augument the prototype:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
  if(!this.prototype[name]){ 
    this.prototype[name] = func;
  }
  return this;
};

Function.method("curry-left", function(){
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice; 
  var that = this;
  var args = slice.call(arguments,0);
  return function(){
    that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.call(arguments,0)));
  }
});
```

Im testing it wiht the following code:

```
function print(arg1, arg2){
  console.log(arg1 + ", " + arg2);
}

print["curry-left"]("hej")("då"); // prints hej, då

var op = {"+":function(a,b){return a + b;}}

console.log(op["+"]["curry-left"](1)(2)) // prints undefined
```

I've tried debugging it and it seems like its the `that` variable in prototype that messing everything up but im not sure why. If i do `console.log(that)` i get `[Function]` as a result, which seems correct

It would be nice if i could get it to work on both instances.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `that` should be a local variable, so `var that = this;`.

Comment: thanks, fixed it but it does not solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your inner function doesn't return a result:

```
Function.method("curry-left", function(){
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice; 
  var that = this;
  var args = slice.call(arguments,0);
  return function(){
    that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.call(arguments,0)));
    ^
  }
});
```

The fix:

```
return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.call(arguments,0)));
```

Comment: @user25470 Don't worry about it, sith happens :)